# ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long 01489. 00000 - "result of string concatenation is too long"

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have this query but I got an  ORA-01489 Error : ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long 01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long", Is it posible resolve this problem maybe setting a system variable ?

```
SELECT "USER_PRIMARY_sector","LOGIN","FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME","sector_ROLE"
FROM (
SELECT user_primary_sector,login, first_name,  last_name,
       LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(rights,' / '))
       KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),' / ') AS sector_ROLE
      FROM  
        (SELECT  login,
              first_name,  
              last_name,
              user_primary_sector,
              rights,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY login ORDER BY rights) AS curr,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY login ORDER BY rights) -1 AS prev
        FROM  (select   member0_.login,  member0_.first_name first_name, sector2.sector_name user_primary_sector,  member0_.last_name last_name,
                        CONCAT(CONCAT(sector.sector_name, ' - '), role3_.role_name) rights 
 from
  TLC_DEVICES.t_member member0_
 inner join  TLC_DEVICES.t_user member0_1_    on member0_.member_id=member0_1_.user_id
 inner join  TLC_DEVICES.t_playable_role playedrole1_    on member0_.member_id=playedrole1_.user_id
 inner join  TLC_DEVICES.t_sector_role sectorrole2_    on playedrole1_.sector_role_id=sectorrole2_.sector_role_id
 inner join  TLC_DEVICES.t_role role3_    on sectorrole2_.role_id=role3_.role_id
 inner join  TLC_DEVICES.t_sector sector    on sectorrole2_.sector_id=sector.sector_id
 inner join  TLC_DEVICES.t_sector sector2    on sector2.sector_id=member0_1_.primary_sector_id
 where    current_date between playedrole1_.start_date and playedrole1_.end_date
 order by sector.sector_name
  ))
GROUP BY login, first_name,  last_name, user_primary_sector
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND login = PRIOR login
START WITH curr = 1
)
ORDER BY user_PRIMARY_sector, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME;
```

Comment: It will help us to help you if you remove bits of your complex query until it still gives the error at it's simplest form.

Comment: Are you really using 11g, or are you using 12c or later?

Comment: I am actually using 12c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to set the `MAX_STRING_SIZE` system variable to `EXTENDED`.
 From the Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020):

> Variable-length character string having maximum length size bytes or characters. You must specify size for VARCHAR2. Minimum size is 1 byte or 1 character. Maximum size is:
>
> 32767 bytes or characters if MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED
>   4000 bytes or characters if MAX_STRING_SIZE = STANDARD

So if your `MAX_STRING_SIZE` is currently set to `STANDARD`, then you will get the `ORA-01489` error if your concatenated string exceeds 4000 bytes or characters.  Here is how you can make the change:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED;
```

If your `MAX_STRING_SIZE` be already set to `EXTENDED`, then you will have to find another way to cope with such long strings.

Comment: That is only possible in `12c` while OP is on `11g`. for any application, it is not a good design if the string aggregation is exceeding that limit at database level. Application use **CLOB** data type for such huge requirements of storage.

Comment: @LalitKumarB He marked this correct which either means he is using `11g` and didn't test it, or is actually using `12c`.  I will delete if he comes back.